# Save first n prime numbers in an array without overwriting it

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to save first 20 prime numbers that are greater or equal than entered number.
Right now the output is 20 times 997 because values overwrite previous ones. I can't figure out what to do to limit them. When the array is full stop the loop or something so the overwriting won't happen?

```c
bool is_prime(int num) {
    if (num < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void fillArr(int arr[20], int num) {
    for (int index = num; index <= 1000; index++) { //don't know how to set up 
    //2nd condition, depends on entered number
        if (is_prime(index)) {
            //save first 20 prime numbers that are >= num into an array
            //Code fills the array with every prime it finds, setting it for all 
            //values and overwriting any previous primes it has found. Right now 
            //output would be the same 20 prime numbers closest to index 1000, 
            //based on second condition
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                arr[i] = index;
            }
        }
    }
    //print test
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

```c
int main() {
        int arr[20];
    int num;

    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    std::cin >> num;

    fillArr(arr, num);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Use a `std:vector<int>` and `push_back()` instead of a raw array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, initialize `i` to `0` at the beginning. Each time you encounter a prime, add it to your array and increment `i`. Break when `i >= 20`.

```
void fillArr(int arr[20], int num) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int index = num; index <= 1000 && i < 20; index++) {
        if (is_prime(index)) {                
            arr[i++] = index;                
        }
    }
    //print test
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

Also note that this is not the most optimal way to find primes. For finding whether a given number is prime, you only need to check for whether it is divisible by primes uptil square root of the number (and not till `n/2`). You may also want to read about the [Seive of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

As also specified in the comments, it's better to use `std::vector` or `std::array` rather than raw arrays. In that case, you'd simply want to `push_back(index)` and `break` when vector's size >= 20.

Comment: I know about `sqrt(num)` but I'm also displaying prime numbers in the range including checking negative numbers`(I know they can't be negative)` I'm just checking and trying different things. As a beginner I don't know about vectors yet but will try them out. Thanks.